# keyword tags structure

Tags: php, mysql

Stackoverflow allows a poster to make tags for their questions.

Now say I have some articles and want to give some keyword tags to each.  I'm using PHP and mysql for this.

What is the best database structure to use when doing this?

Will a limit of 5 keywords per article and unlimited keywords cases require different database structures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is best to normalize your database. You won't find better.

**articles:**
article_id, blablabla

**tags:**
tag_id, title

**tags_to_articles:**
article_id,tag_id

In any case it is best to normalize your databases. Always. Don't worry if you will change your mind and do the limit of tags. Above structure will be always the best because of smallest amount of memory to use.

Comment: I guess when 3 people say nearly the same its the way to go :D

Comment: In terms of textbook structure, this is perfect, but in real world usage, is it a victim of slowdown once many articles get tagged?

Comment: @David19801 No. This structure is really lightweight and you can access to all keywords using only one simple query. Normalization is needed in every database. Read about it, for example in here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Thanks Avail.  Last question, Innodb or Myisam for the three tables?

Comment: @David19801 You won't notice big difference in a small db but Innodb is newer and it has become default mechanism for MySQL databases from v5.5.

Answer (score 0):

You would have 3 tables;

posts       - Here you store all your posts

tags        - Here you store all possible tags

posts_tags  - Here you link your posts to your tags, it could for example have just 3 
columns (id, post_id, tag_id).

The limit of 5 keywords should just be implemented in the interface, the database shouldnt differ. The posts_tags table is called a junction table, it links 2 tables together. The relationship is one-to-many, there is one post with possibly many tags.

Answer (score 0):

i guess it will be good to create many-to-may reference using link table. so i'd create three tables: `articles`, `tags` and `links` to store `article_id` linked to `tag_id`

maybe, one day object orientet databases will replace db's like mysql - they can manage with this task withiut any additioan stuctures... :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of database you're going for.

The most normalized one would look something like this

```
posts - id | title | body | 
tags - id | name |
posts_tags - post_id | tag_id
```

Lookups would be pretty fast and setting up suggestions is simply a matter of looking at your `tags` table.

You could also embed tags directly into your post

```
posts - id | title | body | tags
```

tags would just be a comma separated text field. Normal look ups on this table probably won't be as fast as the other solution, and you'd have to make your set distinct before you can start working on suggestions. An easy fix for this would be to keep a full text capable table of tags as a separate lookup. This works best if you're simply running a full text search system like Sphinx to handle your search.

Also that schema is better suited for noSQL solutions like Mongo where tags is just a subdocument of your posts document.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I don't fully agree with the other answers. My answer would be it depends on your data. How many articles will there be. If it will be a huge number of artilces, the other answers are the way to go. If you have a limited number of articles (and it will always be a small amount) then I would store them in the same table (article_id, article_text, keywords).

Comment: You can't predict the number of articles and/or keywords in the future. You can kill performance that way and force someone to write script that normalizes your database anyway in the future.

Comment: Sure you can, are you creating a personal blog system (you have to work very hard to create 10k articles) or are you creating a new Stack Overflow? And there are more considerations like how often are all or some of the tags updated, how do you search (wildcards?), how often do you search, etc. All I'm trying to say is that you should look at your application to make the best descision and normalization isn't *always8 the best solution.